# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server

Tags: c#, sql-server

[the error what i found when i run the app from another pc (open the link to see the error pic ................................................................](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLDv0.jpg)I don't know why it give me this error ??

Is there something wrong with my code I'm beginner in coding error:

> (timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-J7D5POF;Initial Catalog=ilswork;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=*****;connect timeout=9000");
        public SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-J7D5POF;Initial Catalog=ilswork;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=****;connect timeout=9000");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        int i = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Btexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void Btsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-J7D5POF;Initial Catalog=ilswork;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=*****;connect timeout=9000");
            con.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE etman_interior set Name_Arabic='" + txtName_Arabic.Text + "',gender='" + CBgender.Text + "',NATIONALITY='" + CBNATIONALITY.Text + "',username='" + txtusername.Text + "',Time='" + txttime.Text + "',clock='" + txtclock.Text + "' where CIVILIDD='" + txtCIVILIDD.Text + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            con.Close();


            MessageBox.Show("record updated successfully");
        }

        private void Btnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Close();
            if (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                i++;
                txtCIVILIDD.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CIVILIDD"].ToString();
                txtName_Arabic.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name_Arabic"].ToString();
                txtName_eng.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name_eng"].ToString();
                CBgender.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gender"].ToString();
                CBNATIONALITY.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NATIONALITY"].ToString();


            }
            txtCIVILIDD.Focus();
        }

        private void Btlast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i == ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 || i != 0)
            {
                i--;
                txtCIVILIDD.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CIVILIDD"].ToString();
                txtName_Arabic.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name_Arabic"].ToString();
                txtName_eng.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name_eng"].ToString();
                CBgender.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["gender"].ToString();
                CBNATIONALITY.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NATIONALITY"].ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You on frist record");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Disp_data();
            txtusername.Text = Class1.Txtusername;
            mycon.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from [dbo].[etman_interior]", mycon);
            SqlCommandBuilder bul = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "[dbo].[etman_interior]");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[dbo].[etman_interior]"];
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.ActiveControl = txtCIVILIDD;
            txtCIVILIDD.Focus();

        }
        public void Disp_data()
        {
            mycon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from [dbo].[etman_interior]";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            mycon.Close();

        }

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            this.time_lbl.Text = dateTime.ToString();
            this.txttime.Text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            this.txtclock.Text = dateTime.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                btsave.PerformClick();
            }
            if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                btnext.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you type this in `connect timeout=9000` or you copied the code from somewhere ?

Comment: it did't give me a exactly the line it work in local network with i use it on online network give me this message

Comment: try removing `connect timeout=9000` from the connection string, see if it still blows up

Comment: @ZohirSalak i try it without ( connect timeout = 9000 ) a with it and don't work

Comment: What do you mean by "online network"?

Comment: @KlausGütter i us vpn network to connect the database with another computer

Comment: Where do you get exception? What line?

Comment: @KlausGütter some from work and this form not working and gave me this error

Comment: @Erndob there is no error line when i build the app it show when i open the form after i setup it

Comment: Have a breakpoint and go line by line, to see when it hangs. Absolutely anything in this code could have timed out, now there's no way to know without doing some actual debugging.

Comment: @Erndob pro the app work in my pc bout when i try to us it in another pc gave me this error

Comment: Did you try clicking "details" in that error popup?

Comment: @Erndob yes i try that now

Comment: @Erndob is there any solution to remove the timeout from it ????

Comment: did you remove `connect timeout = 9000`  from all instances ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak yes i try that first after that i bout ( connect timeout = 9000 ) and didn't work

Comment: There's not a single line that would cause timeout other than that, if that's not fixing it, i don't know what will.

Comment: @ZohirSalak thx for you help the last thing did you think is there any problem with the save button ??

Comment: First, why there's three sqlConnection objects, you only need one ? and you need to call `Dispose()` on `SqlDataAdapter sda` also you don't need to close the connection `SqlDataAdapter` does it for you

Comment: Oh and since you're updating the table better use `da.UpdateCommand = update query` then call `UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @ZohirSalak sorry bout can you write to me the right code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues here and several of them are combining to cause your problem...

1. SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter are all IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close them because they will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block.
2. By putting things in `using` blocks rather than keeping them as class-level fields you enforce the scope better, and this will help solve your problem. It also guarantees that things are Closed and Disposed if an exception is thrown.
3. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: avoid using string concatenation to create queries, use parameters instead. Read up on this, it's important.
4. In `Btsave_Click` you're using the SelectCommand of a SqlDataAdapter to do an Update (not a Select). You don't need a SqlDataAdapter here at all, just create an SqlCommand (remember, it's IDisposable, so put it in a `using` block).
5. In `Disp_data` you are calling `ExecuteNonQuery` before using the same command for a SqlDataAdapter. This means it is executing your query twice - remove the ExecuteNonQuery line. ExecuteNonQuery is for SQL things like Insert, Update and Delete; not Select.

Some other less significant tips, and things that at the moment you won't think are worth it, but in a couple of years you might reconsider...

1. Rather than duplicate your connection string, store it in a constant string which you re-use.
2. Consider putting the connection string in the config file and fetching it using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
3. It's a good idea to separate out the code which fetches/stores data from the user interface code. At the moment it's all crammed together, which leads to code which is hard to maintain.
4. In `Btnext_Click` you use `ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]` 5 times in a row. Refactor that to store it in a variable which you reuse, so that it only does those 4 method calls once. Similar for `Btlast_Click`. Consider refactoring these 2 methods so that the similar chunk of code is only written once, and reused from both places.
5. Typo "frist".

Comment: you save my life bro i have an exam and it was a bad night